# change position after calling function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm using swift and I got that function.

func spawnTwo() -> SKSpriteNode {

```
    let two = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "landPic1")
    two.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    two.name = "Obs"
    two.zPosition = 5;
    two.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 , y: 0.5);
    two.position.x = 0
    two.position.y = 0

    self.scene?.addChild(two)


    return two
```

}

now I want, that every time I call that function, 1280 are added the position.x. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep a variable outside of the function:

```
var n = 0
func spawnTwo() -> SKSpriteNode {

    //...
}
```

In the function, you multiply 1280 by `n` and increment `n`:

```
let two = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "landPic1")
two.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
two.name = "\(n)bs" // you might want to change the name each time too
two.zPosition = 5;
two.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 , y: 0.5);
two.position.x = 1280 * n
two.position.y = 0

self.scene?.addChild(two)
n += 1

return two
```